# How do I get "Olympic Spoiler"?

Tags: plague-inc-evolved

I'm having some difficulty getting Olympic Spoiler. I know that you get it after doing something after the Olympics delayed pop-up, but I don't know what actions to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [wiki](http://plagueinc.wikia.com/wiki/Olympic_Spoiler):

> At some point during a game, a popup will say "London Olympics mystery," which says that the London Olympics have been postponed for unknown reasons. This is, we assume, because of your disease. However, this popup can occur even before your disease is discovered.
>
> Some time after this popup has arrived, the player will get a message saying "London Olympics Back On!" If the player evolves Drug Resistance 1, they should eventually get a third popup which will say that "People across the world bring the disease to the UK, it never should have gone ahead!", increasing Infectivity in the UK. If the player doesn't evolve Drug Resistance 1' a pop-up appears stating that "the Olympics a success, good medicine stopped diseases spreading" and the UK remains uninfected. Interestingly, the player can get the "London Olympics Infect UK" message even if the UK was infected before the first popup came. If the player has managed to infect the UK, then the achievement has been earned.

So basically you need to get "Drug Resistance 1" after 1 pop up.